# Laravel Eloquent Database Relationships and Foreign Keys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTransactionsTable extends Migration {

        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
                Schema::create('transactions', function($table) {
                        $table->increments('id');
                        $table->bigInteger('amount');
                        $table->integer('from');
                        $table->integer('to');
                        $table->integer('type');
                        $table->timestamps();
                });

                Schema::create('transaction_types', function($table) {
                        $table->increments('id');
                        $table->string('name');
                });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
                Schema::dropIfExists('transactions');
                Schema::dropIfExists('transaction_types');
        }
}
```

_

```
// app/models/Transactiones.php
class Transaction extends Eloquent {
        public function type()
        {
                return $this->belongsTo('TransactionType');
        }
}
```

_

```
// app/models/TransactionTypes.php
class TransactionType extends Eloquent {
        public function Transactions()
        {
                return $this->hasMany('Transaction', 'type');
        }
}
```

I seeded transaction_types with (1, 'deposit') Now I'm creating a transactions and I want to set the FK of type to the id in transaction_types:

(The code below does not work..)

```
if (0 == Transaction::where('from', $tmpData->refID)->count()) {
        $t = new Transaction();
        $t->amount = $tmpData->amount;
        $t->from = $tmpData->refID;
        $t->to = $tmpData->ownerID1;

        // fails
        $t->type = TransactionType::find(1); // desposit

        // fails
        //$t->types()->insert(TransactionType::find(1)); // desposit

        // If it I do it this way it DOES work, but this seems backwards
        //TransactionType::find(1)->Transactions()->save($t);

        $t->save();
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong? It's just a simple lookup table so when I'm done, I can simply do $transaction->type()->name and display the name.

Also, I'm very new Laravel, so any suggestions on better code is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's not backwards, this is the correct way to do what you want using eloquent.

```
$type = TransactionType::find(1);

$type->transactions()->save(new Transaction(array(
    'amount' => $tmpData->amount,
    'from'   => $tmpData->refID,
    'to'     => $tmpData->ownerID1
)));
```

Comment: What would I do if I had to FK?

Comment: When you say Foreign Key do you mean a true foreign key restraint on the DB? If you mean, how do you assign it to the model, you don't, eloquent does that for you.

Comment: TransactionType is a just a type lookup table for Transactions, There will be other linked tables. I want to link the "to" to the user table (it's the user id). How would I add that into this?